# "Could you please" vs "Could you kindly"

Tags: word-choice, politeness

I am a non-native speaker of English. When communicating with a professor, would it be better to use *could you kindly send me the document* or *could you please send me the document*? I know both are correct, but which one shows more respect?

Comment: You might want to check out the site for [ell.SE], too, in case you have any future questions that may not be a good fit for this site.

Answer (score 26):

Both are polite, and no reasonable professor would take objection to either. If you wanted to sound a little more formal, you could say *I should be most grateful if you would send me the document.*

Comment: Yes, and in any case, a reasonable professor is going to allow for non-native English speakers.

Comment: Why do you use "should" instead of "would" at the beginning of your sentence?

Comment: Because I'm a speaker of British English.

Comment: If the OP is speaking to an American professor, it would probably be better for him to say "I *would* be most grateful if you would send me the document."  I'm an American and I think Barrie England's sentence is a little strange - some might interpret his sentence as "I should be most grateful if you would send me the document, but I wouldn't be."

Comment: "I would be grateful" should be considered incorrect for a different reason: to be grateful does not express a preference or desire, so the use of would would not be redundant (as it is with like); however is it possible or meaningful to use a mood of preference or desire in regard to being grateful? That is, does it make sense to say "I wish to be grateful"? I think ordinarily it does not, so "I should be grateful" is the correct usage in the "classic" system.

Answer (score 13):

If your professor knows you're not a native English speaker, he should be happy with either of those. So the following is purely academic:

"Please" is always the politest word to use when making a request. It is never wrong.

To my British ears, the following phrases have a *very slightly* haranguing tone (as of a nagging mother):

> Would you kindly ...
>
> Would you please ...
>
> Could you kindly ...
>
> Could you please ...

Whereas "Please could you..." is straightforward, conventional, polite and ubiquitous.

Answer (score 12):

I would prefer the word *please* in more formal communications.  *Kindly* would be better-suited for familiar environments.

Also, I would use the word "would" instead of "could."

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using *kindly* rather than *please*. The latter sounds more like begging.

Comment: I also prefer _kindly_, instead of _please_ for the same reason. But I am not sure why this one got so much downvoted.

Comment: @Sudar perhaps because it is just a subjective opinion (sounds like begging) with no citation.